# Get the Value of enum from the class

Tags: enums, enumeration

```
   public class EmpModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}


#region [ Enumeration]

public enum Gender
{
    Male = 0,
    FeMale = 1
}
```

Now how to get enum value
  var employees = root.Elements("Employee");
                foreach (var element in employees)
                {
                    var employee = new EmpModel
                    {

```
                    UserName = element.Element("UserName").Value,
                    FirstName = element.Element("FirstName").Value,
                    LastName=element.Element("LastName").Value,
                    Age=Convert.ToInt32( element.Element("Age").Value),
                    Gender= element.Element("Gender").Value,    // On this line shows error
                   DepartmentId=Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("Department").Value)                            
                };
```

Thanks

Comment: where is your Employee class? What's the type of Gender in that class?

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations in C# are represented by integers (Int32) internally by default. So in this case, if your XML file contains the string "0" or "1", you can simply parse it and then cast it the the correct enum type:

```
Gender = (Gender) Int32.Parse(element.Element("Gender").Value);
```

If you are reading strings that correspond to the names of the Enumeration, you should use Enum.Parse():

```
Gender = (Gender) Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), element.Element("Gender").Value);
```